# Difficulty getting app to appear in Google TV Market

Tags: android, google-tv

I'm trying to get my app to show up on google tv's market, but I'm not having any luck.
I did research and thought I had everything correct in the Manifest.xml, but it's still not showing up. Here's what my manifest looks like...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.whichdiffgtv"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.4" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />


   <uses-feature android:name="com.google.tv" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="com.google.android.tv" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"

            android:name=".WIDgTVActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".act1"

    ></activity>
    </application>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any warning or error message when you published the .apk to the market?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at [the documentation first](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_market_filtering) specifically also the [list of unsupported features](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_android_features#Hardware). Looks like there is no reference to com.google.tv as a feature so remove that.

Answer (score 0):

"com.google.tv" is not a feature supported by Google TV, and will get your app filtered out of the Market.